# which algebraic identity is used in the following equation?

Tags: abstract-algebra

which identity is used to transform the equation from

$$\frac{9x^2}{25}+ \frac{4y^2}{25} = 1$$

to
$$\frac{x^2}{\frac{25}{9}}+ \frac{4y^2}{\frac{25}{4}} = 1$$

Comment: $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{a / c}{b / c}$? Definition of rational numbers (via the equivalence relation)? ...? What are you looking for

Comment: The second term is not correct: $\frac{4y^2}{\frac{25}{4}}\neq \frac{4y^2}{25}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo.

The true "identity" between the two expressions, by reading term to term, reads:

$$\dfrac{9x^2}{25} = \dfrac{x^2}{\dfrac{25}{9}}$$

This is due to the "division by a fraction" rule, which reads:

$$\dfrac{x^2}{\dfrac{b}{c}} = x^2 \cdot \dfrac{c}{b} = \dfrac{x^2c}{b}$$

From this you can by yourself manage to understand the second part of your expression and most of all to notice the typo that is present in the second term (hint: there is a $4$ too much).

Comment: very informative, thank you so much

Comment: @AhmedAbdElGhany If you have read it then why don't you correct the typo then?